# Help dealing with a complex mixture of dependencies, sorting, filtering, and access control

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I've been wrestling with this code for a while, trying to clean it up but it just doesn't feel right. I have a Model, called Library. Libraries can own books, and the Library Model class has a public `books` property which is simply an array of Books. The model might look something like this:

```
Application_Model_Library {
    public $books = null;

    protected $_id;
    protected $_name;

    /* Getters, setters, etc. */
}
```

I also have a Book model. Users can have access to Books which is defined by a many-to-many table, `users_books_permissions`.

The library model stores the number of books the current user has access to, which is found using a `JOIN` on the books table and `COUNT(*)`. Obviously, the library table itself doesn't store this information, so it is a calculated field.

```
protected $_accessibleBookCount;
```

All of my models are contained in one file, with (static) mappers built it. For example:

```
// In the Application_Model_Library class
public static function fetchAll(){
    $db = Zend_Registry::get("db");
    /* etc */
}
```

However, my pagination plugin needs access to the raw `select` statement so it can add the `LIMIT` clause. This is also useful for sorting and filtering. To handle this, fetching a list of books actually requires two calls. The first one creates and returns a `select` object. This is modified in my controller based on the parameters to add sorting, filtering, and paginating. Then, another method in my Model takes the select object and performs the actual fetching and initialing of objects.

The first method is also responsible for injecting the `JOIN` that populates the `$_accessibleBookCount` field.

Fetching a single Library involves getting the `select` statement from the aforementioned function, adding a `WHERE` clause so only the library I want is selected, and then feeding this into the method to actually instantiate the Library model object.

Once I have a library object, fetching its books is handled by a method in the Library model called `getBooks`. If `$books` is null, then the method populates it. Then, the array is returned. Access to individual books can be achieved because the `$books` property is public. Upon fetching, the method also uses a `JOIN` to determine whether the user has access to the book.

However, what if I need to fetch a list of all libraries AND list each library's books at the same time? It's two method calls to get the list of libraries, but then `getBooks` must be called on each Library. This results in A LOT of repeated queries.

Whew. I want to thank anyone who was able to hold on long enough to get to the end of my post. I'd also like to thank anyone ahead of time for their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I see to fetch all books and libraries in one query is to actually fetch for all books and join with the libraries table. This might or might not be a better solution depending on what you are doing with libraries and books in your program.

Something like this (in Books model):

```
$select = $this->select();
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
       ->from(array("b" => "books"))
       ->join(array("l" => "libraries"),"b.lid = l.id",array("libraryName" => "l.name")) // lid = Library ID in Books table
       ->order("l.name ASC"); // Order by Library Name
```

You could then do some PHP magic to sort out Libraries and Books (create new objects,arrays, or whatever you want), for instance:

```
$libraries = array(); 
foreach($books as $book) {
  $libraries[$book->libraryName]["books"][] = $book; 
}
```

You have to see if it's worth the trouble and is faster/more efficient than SQL queries.

Comment: One query isn't necessary. I'm most fearful of this: I call fetchAll on my libraries model to get a list of libraries. But, I need a list of books for each library! So I now have to call fetchAll on each library to get the books. This is 1 + (# of libraries) queries. Currently, I do this: In the library model, fetchAll fetches not only the libraries but also all of the books for each library that will is fetched. Then I use the code you shared in your second snippet to sort them to their rightful owners. Do you think that is a good enough approach?

Comment: The issue I see is that you don't *always* need to fetch the whole lot. Sometimes you just need a simple list of libraries. For example, to populate a "select" form element or something. If you've overwritten fetchAll() method to do much more, then it's just unnecessary workload for simple tasks.

Comment: I can include a parameter in the fetchAll() of the libraries to make the books lazy-load instead

Comment: Well, then just pick one approach or the other! I don't think there is one solution that is much better than the other. If you really want to optimize, time script execution for each approach and select the fastest.

Comment: I mean, when the parameter is set to true, all books are fetched and the libraries are populated. When it is false, just the libraries are fetched; no books. In the latter case, attempting to call `getBooks` on the library will explicitly get the books just for that library.